# Remote Debugging of Website in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, debugging, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I know we can remote debug a website Andriod and Iphone very easily. But is this possible with Windows Phone 8 using Visual Studio or any third party software?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Why don't you just create a simple "simulator" that puts your website in a small iframe? The only (main) difference between a new IE and WP8 should be performance.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach, You are not correct. IE 10 Desktop does'nt support lot of things of IE 10 of Windows Phone 8 like pointers(touch), native Windows 8 functions and so on

Comment: Do you have access to Windows 8? In this case you could try to remote debug with Visual Studio. Or you could try using one of the emulators (either WP8 or tablet). The Windows Phone SDK containts a free VS version (registration needed), it's available here: http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Comment: start from here - [Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Actually its's a live site which work on Andriod and Iphone but not on Windows Phone 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug only on emulator or on device attached to the PC by cable. 
If you don't have any devices, you can test on emulator and then distribute your app as beta and ask friends/colleagues/anyone with device to run the app.

More, you can use [Nokia Remote Device Access program](https://developer.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/) to access different Windows Phones from Nokia (no HTC, sorry).